# Fetch Data From JSON then put in the HTML form

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch-api

I have mini project in react, then I want to fetch data from json server to put in the HTML form. I have no idea how to do.

[image]

[image]

this is how my form and my json look like.

I'm try my best but I'm still don't know how to do this.

Comment: 1) Add some [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to hold your data. 2) Add an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to fetch the data then set it into the state variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use states for your purpose like this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});
const getDataFromServer = () => {
  fetch(...).then(async (response) => {
   const serverData = await response.json();
   setData(serverData);
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Use the "getDataFromServer" frunction in useEffect like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 getDataFromServer();
}, []);
```

And then use the state like this:

```js
  return(
    <div>
     <input name="xl" value={data.xl} />
     <input name="xr" value={data.xr} />
     <input name="function" value={data.function} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please choose my answer as the correct answer if it helped you. Thanks.